# How to generate a stream of JSON from a stream of objects with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-stream

I have a `Stream` of objects and an outgoing `HttpServletResponse`:

```java
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public Int age;
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/my/path", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void getPersons(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Stream<Person> stream = getMyStream();

        // write stream of JSON array to response: [{name: "xx", age: 00}, {...}]
    }
```

How to I generate JSON using Jackson and stream this to the response without filling the memory with all the data?

Answer (score 1):

Jackson comes with a generic [`StreamSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datatypes/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/StreamSerializer.html).
You get it when you add the [`Jdk8Module`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datatypes/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module.html)
to your `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Having done that you can serialize your `Stream<Person>`
very easily:

```
Stream<Person> stream = getMyStream();
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
objectMapper.writeValue(out, stream);
```

Then the JSON output will look like this:

```
[{"name":"Alice","age":30},{"name":"Bob","age":31},{"name":"Charlie","age":32}]
```